# How to send ctrl shift f9 using global send keys in Blue Prism?

Tags: rpa, blueprism

I need to use ctrl + shift + F9 to download a report from SAP window. I cannot use any Code stage for this.

I tried using "{CTRL}{SHIFT}{F9}" and "^+{F9}" but none of them is working. The error I am getting is Input string was not in a correct format.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use Global Send Key Events after using activate application and pass the below as the input for the Global Send Key Events:

```
<{CTRL}<{SHIFT}{F9}>{SHIFT}>{CTRL}
```